# PHP API request acceleration

Tags: php, api

I'm pulling data through a CURL API request as outlined below:

```
<?php

$username = "xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyy";
$password = "xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyyxxxxyyyyxxxxyyyy";
$remote_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/orders.json';

for ($pages = 0; $pages <= 1420; $pages++)

{
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password");
$headers[] =  "X-Page:" . $pages;

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => $headers
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file1 = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

echo "<br><br>Starting page number $pages pull...";

$data = json_decode($file1, true);

foreach($data as $innerArray) {

/******** WRITE DATA TO DATABASE ********/
```

The problem is there are over 1,400 pages which makes the process very slow. Is there a way to make this process faster, for example splitting the 1,400 pages into query chunks that can be run at the same time?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Can you use wget or curl on the command line?  Just to get the data?  You should also check where the bottleneck is using microtome().

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is to be achieved on both remote request types - cURLing a remote server AND querying the DB.

Regarding the cURL, unless you have a different way to get the pages from the remote server you will have to receive each page at a time, just like the solution you've provided. This is very inefficient because fetching each of the pages requires opening a new stream and waiting for an answer. It would be much faster if you could initiate a single cURL to fetch ALL pages.

Regarding the insertion to DB, it is very inefficient to query it for each page at a time. It would be much faster if you could use a single query to insert ALL pages.

The method of a single insertion for multiple values varies between DB's and might be difficult to implement, especially when dealing with MySql. But that's a matter for another thread.